# Page number 107 : An Invitation to Algebraic Geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This section is telling me that rational maps are from a dense open subset of a variety, then it gives me an example of projection onto a hyperplane.

Could someone give me details about why this map is from a dense subset?

The point in the example does not even appear to be dense to me because if I consider another point then every open set (which is the complement of a variety) does not contain it; for instance when a circle around a different point defines an open set the projected point could be in the outside part of the variety, which I think makes the point not dense..

[page 107](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzK4O.png)
[my sketch of a counterexample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETxnL.png)

Comment: The map is defined at every point except $p$.

Comment: 1: I've added a new picture to the question.

2: Does that mean "every point is dense except for $p$?"

Comment: You are misusing the word dense. The set of points where the map is defined, namely $\mathbb{P}^n\setminus\{p\}$, is a dense set in $\mathbb{P}^n$.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to say that a point is not dense.